# Pass variable to a component Laravel 9

Tags: php, laravel

I have my main page and in it, I am using component like this  and I have a Controller for the main page and from there I am passing variable categories like this:

Main page:

```
<h1>Hello</h1>
<x-component>
```

Controller:

```
public function main_page() {
$categories = Category::all();
return view('main_page', compact('categories');
}
```

Inside that main page, I can @foreach those variable $categories, but when I want to @foreach it inside my called  It shows that variable is not found. How to pass $categories to this component?

Comment: You need to pass it as an array to `view`, as in `return view('main_page', ['categories'=>$categories]);`.

Comment: Still -> Undefined variable $categories

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add props in your component

```
<x-component :categories="$categories">
```

Also you should add this in your component

```
public $categories;

public function __construct($categories)
{
    $this->categories = $categories;
}
```

I recommend you read [this](https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/blade#passing-data-to-components) article